# Is there a way to find/display only the posts tagged on a specific location (i.e. Bali) by IG user?

Tags: api, instagram

The purpose would be to find content from the people you follow that were tagged to a location.

I cant seem to find the correct information on the developer page

except to creating photo containers (not a public api) or having to authenticate

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media#get-media